# SASS/Compass is missing one entry in @each when using compressed output

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

Following SCSS snippet generates the appropriate CSS after using `compass compile`. But if I use `-output_style compressed` the CSS is missing the `.box-yellow` definition. `.box-red` etc. is generated but yellow is missing.

```
$colors: red #f00, yellow #ff0, green #0f0, blue #00f;

@each $entry in $colors {
    $name: nth($entry, 1);
    $color: nth($entry, 2);

    .box-#{$name} > header {
         background: $color;
    }
 }
```

Could this be a bug or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it's a bug, but it seems odd to me. I can replicate that here with v 3.2.3 if I set the style to compressed. Oddly, shortening it to `yello` works fine. A workaround is to quote them:

```
$colors: "red" #f00, "yellow" #ff0, "green" #0f0, "blue" #00f;
```

That generates:

```
.box-red>header{background:red}.box-yellow>header{background:#ff0}.box-green>header{background:lime}.box-blue>header{background:blue}
```

And now that I look at the output again, a pattern emerges: The other colors generate a color name rather than a hex value.

Comment: Yes, I also temporarily solved it changing it to `yello`. Thanks for the tip with the quotes, works great.

Comment: @Dehalion Happy to help. It might be worth reporting that over at the [Sass issues section at github](https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues)

Comment: Had already created an Issue for the Compass project and now also at Sass directly (https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/665)

Comment: And I figured out why yellow uses a hex value, Sass picks the shortest, so the the shorthand hex value is shorter than the color name.

Comment: Aah, that's clever. But then they should check if `yellow` is used as colour or as class or file name